# How to filter by elements in an array (or nested object) in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My data is as follows:

```
[
  {
    orgId: "ABC",
    categories: [
      "music",
      "dance"
    ]
  },
  {
    orgId: "XYZ",
    categories: [
      "math",
      "science",
      "art"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I have the primary key on `orgId`, and I want to use DynamoDB `query` to filter and return only items with category "science," for example.

(Category does not need to be part of any index: I am willing to accept the additional worker overhead, provided that I can do the query within Dynamo itself.)

I am having a dickens of a time getting this working. I can readily change `categories` into nested objects if that would help?

But the comparison operators are so limited in DynamoDB that it appears there is no way to filter by array elements, or nested objects?

If not, what's the better approach here? To turn each category into its own first level attribute, such as:

```
[
  {
    orgId: "XYZ",
    category_math: true,
    category_science: true
  }
]
```

Surely not?

Answer (score 7):

```
 var params = {
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ":orgIdValue": {
     S: "XYZ"
    },
   ":categoriesValue": {
     S: "science"
    }
  }, 
  KeyConditionExpression: "orgId = :orgIdValue", 
  FilterExpression : "categories CONTAINS :categoriesValue", 
  TableName: "MYTABLE"
 };
 dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

> CONTAINS : Checks for a subsequence, or value in a set.
>   AttributeValueList can contain only one AttributeValue element of type
>   String, Number, or Binary (not a set type). If the target attribute of
>   the comparison is of type String, then the operator checks for a
>   substring match. If the target attribute of the comparison is of type
>   Binary, then the operator looks for a subsequence of the target that
>   matches the input. **If the target attribute of the comparison is a set
>   ("SS", "NS", or "BS"), then the operator evaluates to true if it finds
>   an exact match with any member of the set. CONTAINS is supported for
>   lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a" can be a list**; however, "b"
>   cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

Categories is a top level attribute, you don't actually have any nested attributes. Top level scalar attributes can be indexed. Although categories is top level its not a scalar attribute (its a set), so you cannot index it.

You can use a FilterExpression to narrow down your query, and you can use the CONTAINS comparator on lists.

Comment: Thanks. That *should* work, but for whatever reason it doesn't. It returns `Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "CONTAINS"`. However, it lead me to a solution which does work (using [DocumentClient SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property)): `{ ... QueryFilter: { categories: { ComparisonOperator: "CONTAINS", AttributeValueList: [myCategoryVariable], } ... }`

Answer (score 4):

The answer posted above should work, per the documentation. But when using the Node.JS AWS DynamoDB SDK's [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property), it doesn't. Particularly, I tried:

```
  {
    TableName: "site",
    IndexName: "orgId-lastCaptured-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "orgId = :orgId",
    FilterExpression: "categories CONTAINS :categoriesValue",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":orgId": orgId,
      ":categoriesValue": myVariable,
    }
  }
```

This resulted in the following error: `{ ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "CONTAINS", near: "categories CONTAINS :categoriesValue"`

I adjusted the query to the alternative query formatting as follows:

```
  {
    TableName: "site",
    IndexName: "orgId-lastCaptured-index",
    KeyConditions: {
      orgId: {
        ComparisonOperator: "EQ",
        AttributeValueList: [orgId],
      },
    },
    QueryFilter: {
      categories: {
        ComparisonOperator: "CONTAINS",
        AttributeValueList: [myVariable],
      }
    }
  }
```

This worked as anticipated, filtering the returned results such that `categories` variable has an element that matches `myVariable`.

Update: You can now do `CONTAINS` operations without using the deprecated `QueryFilter` with this syntax: `FilterExpression: "contains(categories, :categoriesValue)"`